# Excel Median with nested if statement with wildcards

Tags: excel, if-statement, wildcard, median

[data table]

[image]

[support case data set - has 36k rows]

[image]

I'm trying to build dashboards for my co's support team. I can calculate average response times (I have four times I need to take an average & median) with a pivot table but median has to be formula-based. To make things easier, I want the support manager to be able to search by three parameters 1)Agent Name, 2)Category, 3)Priority. All the data is in my 'select data' tab and the formula I have is:

```
{=MEDIAN(IF($B$2='select data'!$E:$E,IF($C$2='select data'!$F:$F,IF($D$2='select data'!$K:$K,'select data'!S:S))))}
```

.

```
b2=agent name, c2=category, d2=priority
```

I'm using a drop down menu for the three categories and when I select a specific agent, category or priority, it spits out the result I need. When I try to use `*` or `"*"` in the drop down to capture all agents/categories/priorities, the formula spits out a `#Num` error.

Comment: *When i try to use * or "*" * - can you post a screenshot of some examples of what you are doing and the data structure? It will help us help you tremendously.

Comment: so my drop down list is built from a separate sheet:

Agent Name    
tom
eric
etc
(blank)
"*"

Category
cat 1
cat 2
etc
(blank)
*

Prioitiy
1
2
etc
(blank)
*

Comment: i'm sorry as i'm having trouble dropping my screenshot in the comments section of the site.

Comment: you can edit your original question and add screenshots

Comment: thanks, fixed it
the first link is a screenshot of my drop down, the second is of the first 2 rows (of 36K) of my data dump. I am taking the median of the last 4 columns (s-v)

Comment: so you want the formula to account for 1 or all of the three parameters. So if only agent name is selected find the median for that, or if agent-name and category are selected for that combination and so on ...?

Comment: Yes Scott, that is correct. I want the formula to evaluate for each individual situation (agent, category, priority) which it currently does - when the data table shows a value (eric, cat 1, p1) the formula provides a real result. 

when any of the three fields shows the all character (i've used * and "*"), the formula breaks down.

Comment: in terms of formulas, you'll probably have to use nested `IF` statements, which is going to get real ugly real quick. That said, look into the [`AGGREGATE'](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) function. It may help (if you have XL 2010 or greater.